# Javascript is not working properly inside djagno project

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

While my code is working when used outside of a Django project, when I place it inside one it's acting strange.
More specifically, the `document` object does not have a body, but only the head of my html. Thus I am not able to access its classes. My guess is that something's wrong in the linking between the html and js files.

**settings.py**

```py
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>index.html</title>
    {% load static %} 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}"/>
    <script src="{% static 'script.js' %}"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    HelloWorld!
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML)
```

The return of **script.js**:

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>index.html</title>
     
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css">
    <script src="/static/script.js"></script></head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wait until your HTML completely loaded and parsed before accessing it.

Just wrap your script by

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML)
});
```

or place your script right before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: Ok this makes sense! And it works! so, DOM is the document and I wait until its loaded, right? One more question: why do I need to do this when used inside a django project but not when used outside one?

Comment: not sure what do you mean by using inside django and outside. Actually the waiting for DOM loaded is not related to django or any frameworks. I may assume something different in placing your script tag

Comment: What I mean by "outside django" is when I load my `index.html` by hand on a browser without placing it in a template folder inside a django project. In other words, when I am not using django at all, so my app has front-end only. In that case no errors are shown. However, in the case I run my page inside a django project, meaning I run the django server (`python manage.py runserver`) that returns the `index.html` I am getting the error. But this is solved when I use `DOMContentLoaded`, but I do not understand why it is not needed in the first case.

Comment: you could check where you place the script in the first case. I assume it is placed after all HTML, somewhere at the bottom of body. But django places it at the top, before HTML

Comment: Wait, what do you mean by "place the script"? Is this where I link it to my html?

Comment: yes, this is where you put your `<script src="/static/script.js"></script>`

Comment: I put it in the head of my html file. Isn't it supposed to run before the body was loaded?

Comment: yes, it's supposed to run before the body loaded